Clarification on definition and proposition

It states that X is independent of Z conditioning on Y if $p(x,y,z)p(y)=p(x,y)p(y,z)$. In other words $p(x,y,z)p(y)=p(x,y)p(y,z)$, implies $X \perp Z|Y$, right?
I then have to prove the following:

So, in order to prove the only if part of the proposition, I would have to assume $X \perp Z|Y$ and then show $p(x,y,z) = a(x,y)b(y,z)$. However, from my understanding of definition 2.4, $p(x,y,z)p(y)=p(x,y)p(y,z)$, implies $X \perp Z|Y$. Not the other way around.
Thus, the issue I am facing is how I cannot make use $p(x,y,z)p(y)=p(x,y)p(y,z)$ because I have to assume $X \perp Z|Y$ in order to prove the "only if" part of the question.  Also, I am confident that I have to use definition 2.4. I presume there's a flaw in my logic.
Note: the images are from "Information theory and Network Coding" 978-0-387-79233-0

What are $a$ and $b$ ?

Arbitrary functions. So, from what I understand, (2.5) states that there are functions a and b such that p(x,y,z) can be factorized into the product of a and b.

Your confusion seems to be here:

However, from my understanding of definition 2.4, $p(x,y,z)p(y)=p(x,y)p(y,z)$, implies $X \perp Z|Y$. Not the other way around.

which comes from here:

It states that X is independent of Z conditioning on Y if $p(x,y,z)p(y)=p(x,y)p(y,z)$.

But in fact, 2.4 is a definition, which means it is (in some sense) a "if and only if" relation.
It should be read as "For random variables X,Y,Z, when we say that X is independent on Z conditioning on Y, we mean that (insert formula 2.3)"
A definition is an introduction of a concept/terminology/notation. Indeed, using "if and only if" there would have been more precise, but this can be assumed from it being a definition.
